# Python: How to reduce computation time in python

Tags: python-3.x, time

I have written the following to code to **find largest prime factor of the number 600851475143** but the computation time is too large. Is there anything I can do to reduce the computation time. Thanks!

```
def factor(n):
    answer = [] 
    for i in range(1,(n//2) + 1):
        if n%i == 0:
            print(i)
            answer.append(i)
    return answer        

def prime_factor(n):
    l = n[:]     
    for i in n:
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i%j == 0:
                l.remove(i)
                break
    return l  
print(prime_factor(factor(600851475143)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is pretty quick

```
num = 600851475143
factor = 2 
while num > 1:
    while num % factor == 0:
        num = num//factor
    factor+=1

print(factor - 1)
```

Take the number and start dividing it by integers(start from 2) repeatedly until you can't. Now try for the next integer and then the next and so on...
The last `factor` with which you can divide `num` will be the greatest prime.

Pretty obvious once it clicks. Have fun problem solving :)

Comment: Oh wow! This is a very elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: There are more efficient methods than this one. You can make it even better.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep at it.